# guild возвращает None discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

bot.get_guild() возвращает None. Если провести эту операцию в функции on_ready(), то все получится, но как мне потом вытащить из on_ready() этот guild и использовать в других функциях, например on_message и @bot.command ?

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = bot.get_guild(Id_server)
```

Answer (score 0):

В `on_message` и `bot.command` приходят дополнительные объекты контекста. Например в `on_message` приходит объект типа `discord.Message`, у которого есть атрибут `guild` (`message.guild`), а во все команды (`bot.command`) приходят объекты `commands.Context`, из которых так же можно достать сервер (`ctx.guild`)